# Is $\frac{4x^2 - 1}{3x^2}$ an abundancy outlaw?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $x$.  For example, $\sigma(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 12$.

We call the ratio $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ the **abundancy index** of $x$.  A number $y$ which fails to be in the image of the map $I$ is said to be an **abundancy outlaw**.

My question is:

> Is $$\frac{4x^2 - 1}{3x^2}$$ an abundancy outlaw?

In this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Holdener/holdener7.pdf), it is mentioned that if $r/s$ is an abundancy index with $\gcd(r,s) = 1$, then $r \geq \sigma(s)$.

Note that 
$$\gcd(4x^2 - 1, 3x^2) = \gcd(x^2 - 1, 3x^2) = 1$$
if $x \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Hence, if $(4x^2 - 1)/3x^2$ is an abundancy index with $x \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $4x^2 - 1 \geq \sigma(3x^2)$.

Here is where I get stuck.  (I would like to affirmatively answer my question via the contrapositive.)

Lastly, if $(4x^2 - 1)/3x^2$ were an abundancy index $I(y)$, then
$${3x^2}\sigma(y) = y(4x^2 - 1),$$
so that
$${3x^2}\left(\sigma(y) - y\right) = y(x^2 - 1).$$

Since $\gcd(x^2, x^2 - 1) = 1$, I am sure that $x^2 \mid y$ and $(x^2 - 1) \mid \left(3(\sigma(y) - y))\right)$.  So I can write
$$y = kx^2$$
and
$$3(\sigma(y) - y) = m(x^2 - 1).$$
I am not too sure though, how this can help in answering my question.

**Update [October 10, 2015 - 1:05 PM]:**  Additionally, $I(y) = (4x^2 - 1)/3x^2 < 4/3$, so that $3(\sigma(y) - y) < y$.

Comment: sorry about that .i shouldn't do this when im too tired to  do arithmetic. i deleted my comment.

Comment: That's okay, I'll delete mine too.

Answer (score 1):

**A partial answer.**

Let $I(y)=\frac{4x^2 - 1}{3x^2}$.

If $\gcd(4x^2 - 1, 3x^2) = 1$ then $3$ is a factor of $y$ contradicting the fact that $I(y)<\frac{4}{3}$.

Therefore $\gcd(4x^2 - 1, 3x^2) = 3$.

Comment: Furthermore, it follows that $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.