# If $\frac{σ(x)}{x}=\frac{p+2}p$ where $p$ is an odd prime, does it follow that $x$ is an odd square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

(This question is related to the latest comment underneath this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090850).)

Let
$$\sigma(x)=\sum_{d \mid x}{d}$$
be the sum of the divisors of $x$.

Denote the abundancy index of $x$ by $$I(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}.$$

Here is my question:

> If $I(x)=\dfrac{p+2}{p}$, where $p$ is an odd prime, does it follow that $x$ is an odd square?

From the equation
$$p\sigma(x)=(p+2)x$$
I can only prove that $x$ is an odd square *when $x$ is odd*.  But what about if $x$ is even?

That is, if $I(x) = \dfrac{p+2}{p}$, where $p$ is an odd prime, must it necessarily be the case that $x$ is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that for any coprime $a, b \in \mathbb{N}_+$, there is$$
I(ab) = I(a) I(b).
$$

Suppose there is an even number $n = 2^k \cdot l$, where $k \geqslant 1$ and $l$ odd, such that$$
I(n) = \frac{p + 2}{p}.
$$

**Case 1:** $k \geqslant 2$. Then$$
\frac{p + 2}{p} = I(2^k \cdot l) = I(2^k) I(l) \geqslant I(2^k) = \frac{2^{k + 1} - 1}{2^k} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^k} \geqslant \frac{7}{4},
$$
which implies $4(p + 2) \geqslant 7p$, contradictory to $p \geqslant 3$.

**Case 2:** $k = 1$ and $p \geqslant 5$. Then, analogously,$$
\frac{p + 2}{p} \geqslant 2 - \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{3}{2},
$$
which implies $2(p + 2) \geqslant 3p$, contradictory to $p \geqslant 5$.

**Case 3:** $k = 1$ and $p = 3$. Then$$
\frac{5}{3} = I(2l) = \frac{3}{2} I(l) \Longrightarrow I(l) = \frac{10}{9}.
$$

If $l$ has an odd prime factor $q < 10$, suppose $q^m \mathrel{\|} l$, then$$
\frac{10}{9} = I(l) = I(q^m) I\left( \frac{l}{q^m} \right) \geqslant I(q^m) = \frac{q^{m + 1} - 1}{q^m (q - 1)}\\
= 1 + \frac{1}{q - 1}\frac{q^m - 1}{q^m} \geqslant 1 + \frac{1}{q - 1}\frac{q - 1}{q} = 1 + \frac{1}{q} > \frac{10}{9},
$$
a contradiction. Now suppose the prime factorization of $l$ is$$
l = \prod_{i = 1}^s p_i^{a_i},
$$
then $p_i \geqslant 11$. Because$$
\frac{10}{9} = I(l) = \prod_{i = 1}^s \frac{1 + p_i + \cdots + p_i^{a_i}}{p_i^{a_i}},
$$
then$$
9 \prod_{i = 1}^s \sum_{j = 0}^{a_i} p_i^j = 10 \prod_{i = 1}^s p_i^{a_i} \Longrightarrow \left. 9 \,\middle|\, \prod_{i = 1}^s p_i^{a_i} \right.,
$$
contradictory to $p_i \geqslant 11$.

Therefore, there does not exist an even positive integer $n$ such that$$
I(n) = \frac{p + 2}{p}.
$$

Comment: Thanks @AlexFrancisco, I honestly did not see this coming. Is this your own proof?  Otherwise, care to share the online reference from where this proof is lifted?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris This is my original proof.

Comment: Dude, you should have that published.  I do not remember seeing such a proof in the literature.

Comment: Hi again, @AlexFrancisco.  I seem to have spotted an error in your proof just now.  In the part where you assumed that $l$ has a prime factor $q < 10$, which implies that $1/q > 1/10$, then $1 + (1/q) > 11/10$, which is not greater than $10/9$.

Comment: But I think that your proof is leading to a hint that $q \leq 9$ (since $q$ must be prime), so that
$$10/9 \geq I(q^m) \geq 1 + (1/q) \geq 10/9,$$
which implies that $I(q^m) = 10/9$.  This contradicts the fact that $10/9$ is an abundancy outlaw (since $9 < 10 < \sigma(9) = 1 + 3 + 9 = 13$ and $9$ is relatively prime to $10$).  See this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Holdener/holdener7.pdf) by Holdener and Stanton for more.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris If $q$ is a **prime** and $q < 10$, then $q < 9$ also holds.

Comment: Hi @AlexFrancisco.  Yes, you are right!  I missed that!  =)

Comment: Hi again, @AlexFrancisco.  We would like to include your proof here as additional material content for our paper, submitted to NNTDM.  In this regard, may we invite you as a co-author?  If you do not wish to become a co-author, may we have your permission to include your proof in our paper?  You may reach me at josearnaldobdris AT gmail DOT com.  Thank you!  =)

Comment: Hi @AlexFrancisco.  I sent you an e-mail.  Please check.  Thank you!  =)

Answer (score 1):

p must divide x and so we can suppose that 2p is a factor of x. Then I(2p) is no greater than (p+2)/p which is clearly false.

Comment: +1 for the simple proof! =)

Comment: Thanks Jose. You may also be interested to note that a similar reasoning applies to your problem 1472823 where your initial gcds being 1 would imply that 3 divides y and then the index would have to be bigger than 4/3.

Comment: I invite you to write your last comment out as a complete answer to [that other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1472823), @S.Dolan, so that I will be able to accept it.  =)

Comment: Just double-checking your argument, @S.Dolan:  Assume that $x$ is even.  Then we have:
$$p \mid x \text{ and } x \text{ even } \implies 2p \mid x \implies \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{p+1}{p} = I(2)I(p) = I(2p) \leq I(x) = \frac{p+2}{p}$$
from which it follows that
$$3(p+1) \leq 2(p+2) \implies 3p + 3 \leq 2p + 4 \implies p \leq 1,$$
which contradicts the fact that $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I considered.