# If $\sigma(n)/n = 5/3$, then $5 \nmid n$. Does it also follow that $3 \nmid \sigma(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.  If $\sigma(N)=2N$ (equivalently, when $I(N)=2$) then $N$ is called a *perfect number*.  Both $\sigma$ and $I$ are [multiplicative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).

It is easy to prove the following:

> If $I(n) = 5/3$, then $5 \nmid n$.

**Proof**

Suppose that $I(n)=5/3$.  By this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2676213/28816), we know that $n$ must be an odd square.

Hence $3^2 \mid n$ (since $n$ is a square and $3\sigma(n)=5n$, where we notice that $\gcd(3,5)=1$, so that $3 \mid n$).  If it is also the case that $5 \mid n$, then $5^2 \mid n$ (again, since $n$ is a square), so that we obtain
$$1.\overline{666} = \frac{5}{3}=I(n) \geq I(3^2)I(5^2) = \frac{13}{9}\cdot\frac{31}{25} = \frac{403}{225} = 1.79\overline{1},$$
which is a contradiction.

Hence, $5 \nmid n$, and $5n$ would be an odd perfect number if there exists an $n$ such that $I(n)=5/3$:
$$I(5n) = I(5)I(n) = \frac{6}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{3} = 2.$$

Here is my question in this post:

> If $\sigma(n)/n = 5/3$, does it also follow that $3 \nmid \sigma(n)$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Assume that $3 \nmid \sigma(n)$.  We can apply the $\sigma$ function to both sides of $3\sigma(n)=5n$, thereby yielding
$$\sigma(3\sigma(n))=\sigma(5n).$$
Since $3$ and $5$ are primes, $5 \nmid n$, and $3 \nmid \sigma(n)$ by assumption, then
$$\gcd(3,\sigma(n))=\gcd(5,n)=1.$$
Using the fact that $\sigma$ is multiplicative, we get
$$\sigma(3)\sigma(\sigma(n))=\sigma(3\sigma(n))=\sigma(5n)=\sigma(5)\sigma(n)$$
so that we obtain
$$I(\sigma(n))=\frac{\sigma(\sigma(n))}{\sigma(n)}=\frac{\sigma(5)}{\sigma(3)}=\frac{6}{4}=\frac{3}{2}.$$
This last equation implies that $\sigma(n)=2$, which violates the fact that $n$ is an odd square.

We therefore conclude that $3 \mid \sigma(n)$.

Comment: I don't understand this: This last equation implies that $\sigma(n)=2$.

Comment: @greedoid: Thank you for your comment. That implication basically means that the only positive integer $x$ satisfying $I(x) = 3/2$ is $x = 2$, since primes are solitary.

Comment: How do you know $\sigma(n)$ is a prime?

Comment: @greedoid:  The abundancy index of a prime $p$ is of the form $(p+1)/p$.  I invite you to check out the [Wolfram MathWorld page on solitary numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html) if you have not done so yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY ATTEMPT**

Assume that $3 \nmid \sigma(n)$.  We can apply the $\sigma$ function to both sides of $3\sigma(n)=5n$, thereby yielding
$$\sigma(3\sigma(n))=\sigma(5n).$$
Since $3$ and $5$ are primes, $5 \nmid n$, and $3 \nmid \sigma(n)$ by assumption, then
$$\gcd(3,\sigma(n))=\gcd(5,n)=1.$$
Using the fact that $\sigma$ is multiplicative, we get
$$\sigma(3)\sigma(\sigma(n))=\sigma(3\sigma(n))=\sigma(5n)=\sigma(5)\sigma(n)$$
so that we obtain
$$I(\sigma(n))=\frac{\sigma(\sigma(n))}{\sigma(n)}=\frac{\sigma(5)}{\sigma(3)}=\frac{6}{4}=\frac{3}{2}.$$
This last equation implies that $\sigma(n)=2$, which violates the fact that $n$ is an odd square.

We therefore conclude that $3 \mid \sigma(n)$.

Comment: Aha!  From this [closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090850), we have that if $I(n) = (p+2)/p$ where $p$ is an odd prime, then
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) = \frac{n}{p} = \frac{\sigma(n)}{p+2} = \frac{s(n)}{2} = \frac{D(n)}{p - 2},$$
where $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the *aliquot sum* of the positive integer $x$, and where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of $x$.

Comment: In particular, since both $3 \mid n$ and $3 \mid \sigma(n)$ are true, then $3 \mid \gcd(n,\sigma(n))$ holds.  Since $p=3$ in the present problem, then this means that
$$6 \mid s(n), 3 \mid D(n).$$
In fact, since $p=3$, then $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))=D(n)$ ought to hold.

Comment: We infer that $s(n)$ must be **abundant**.

Answer (score 0):

**Another (shorter) approach:**

Since $3\sigma(n)=5n$ and $n$ is an odd square, then $3^2 \mid n$.  If $3 \nmid \sigma(n)$, then $3^2 \nmid \text{LHS}$, contradicting $3^2 \mid \text{RHS}$.